# The difference between “sich darauf freuen” and “sich darüber freuen”?

Tags: word-usage, difference, word-choice, pronominal-adverb

I often come across following two types of usage of *sich freuen*, i.e.,

1. Ich freue mich darauf, …
2. Ich freue mich darüber, …

Both are used in the sense of “I am delighted about/over it” or in case of a longer sentence in the sense of “I am looking forward to …” My question is how one determines whether one should use *darauf* or *darüber* in the above sentences, are there any specific rules one should keep in mind?

Comment: This is actually a dictionary question!

Comment: A similar question is discussed [**here**](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/35427/fixed-prepositions-sich-freuen-auf-%C3%BCber/35431)

Answer (score 7):

Simply speaking, the two phrases have two slightly different meanings. Whereas one might be delighted about a gift they have (already) received (from the present point to a point in the past), if you anticipate an event, such as going to your favourite concert next week, you will use *sich darauf freuen* instead of *sich darüber freuen*.

Here are some examples:

> **Ich freue mich schon darauf.**
>   *I am already excited about it (future event)* 
>   
>   **Er freut sich so darauf.**
>   *He is so exicted/delighted/in high anticipation of it. (future event)*/

And some more examples:

> **Danke! Ich freue mich darüber!**
>   *Thank you, I am (currently) delighted about it! (present event)*
>   
>   **Er freut sich so darüber.**
>   *He is so delighted about it. (present event)*
>   
>   **Sie hat sich so darüber gefreut.**
>   *She was so delighted about it. (past event)*

A little more:

Note that *darüber* as well as *darauf* are always representing a noun, and often the subject in a sentence. This way, you will say:

> Ich freue mich **auf** das **Konzert**

but if the relative word, *Konzert*, is missing:

> Ich freue mich auch **darauf**.

Answer (score 5):

This is actually a dictionary question:

> Sich freuen auf/darauf
>   To look forward to

Whereas

> Sich freuen über
>   To be happy/glad about smth./To rejoice over

`Ich freue mich darauf` **is not** used in the sense of `I'm delighted over/about it`! That would be `I'm looking forward to`.

Answer (score 0):

The difference carries over from the respective differences of the prepositional objects the verb *freuen* can take. The *dar-* forms are merely demonstrative pronouns to avoid repeating the same noun.

> Sich **auf** etwas freuen

This does not mean *to be delighted about something*. Its only meaning is *to be excited about something*, something necessarily being a future event.

> Sich **über** etwas freuen

This is the phrase you are looking for for *to be delighted about something*.

Compare the following examples:

> Ich freue mich auf das Eishockeyspiel.
>
> Morgen ist das Eishockeyspiel. Ich freue mich darauf.

The ice hockey match is tomorrow and the speaker is *looking forward to it*. Note the demonstrative preposional pronoun *darauf* in the second example.

> Ich freue mich über das Eishockeyspiel.

(It’s a little bit harder to generate a sentence wherein *darüber* clearly refers to the game and only the game. I expect suggestions to appear in the comments or edited in accordingly ;-))

Here, the match has happened. *Something* about the match was so great, that the speaker is delighted about the match as a whole.