# Fixed prepositions (sich freuen auf/über)

Tags: german-to-english, standard-german

Where do we use *sich freuen auf* and *sich freuen über*

Comment: More context please! Give us examples of sentences where you feel uncertain.

Answer (score 1):

Basically

> **(a)** sich freuen auf = Vorfreude *(happy anticipation)*

refers to the future (e. g. vacation; end of the lesson)
while

> **(b)** sich freuen über = Freude (*pleasure*)

refers to the present (e. g. a sudden visit of a loved person).

**(a)** is always connected with expectation, **(b)** with surprise or prior uncertainty, doubt, fear (e. g. concerning the result of an examination).